# Little hint for solving a question (measure theory)

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I just want to know where to start... the question is

If $A\subset [0,1]$ and $\mu(A)>0$ where $\mu$ is a Lebesgue measure on Lebesgue measurable space, then there are $x,y\in A$ such that $|xy|$ is an irrational number.

What I think is first I need to show that there exists $x,y \in A$ irrational numbers. This is easy to show as if $A$ contains only rational number, then it must have $\mu(A)=0$. But then, I am not sure how to show $xy$ is irrational...

Comment: If two irrationals $x,y$ multiply to give a rational then there exists a rational $q$ such that $x=q/y$. This defines an equivalence relation on the irrationals. You need to show that the equivalence classes of this have measure zero. The obvious thing to check is whether they are countable, but they might have measure zero anyway.

Comment: @Ian One thought strikes me is following the same step as the proof of existence of non-measurable set.. Am I going to the right direction?

Comment: The Lebesgue measure of the set of $x$ with $x^2$ rational is zero. So $x^2$ is irrational for almost all $x\in A$, taking one of those (existing, since $\mu(A)>0$) for $x=y$ will turn the trick.